# jQuery autocomplete autofill enabled

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, autofill

I am using the core jQuery UI autocomplete and it works perfectly, but I need to have the input field filled in as I type.

For example if I enter Ger the rest of the country name (many) should appear in grey. An the text I typed in black.

How can I achieve this with the core plugin? I belive it is called autofill but all the 3rd party plugins that I have tested does not work entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery/ Javascript - Google suggest inside textarea (no dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111355/jquery-javascript-google-suggest-inside-textarea-no-dropdown)

Comment: I need it to work with the default jQuery UI autocomplete.